# How to import a string from a file using SASS?

Tags: sass

Example: I want to import SVG from a file (to hard-code it in the CSS), e.g.

```scss
$svg-icon: @import('./icon.svg');
```

Is this possible at all using SASS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299453/inline-svg-from-a-file-with-sass

Comment: This is a more generic question.

Comment: What you're asking for requires a custom function injected with SassScript (ie. written in Ruby), Sass doesn't provide one.

Comment: See also the last answer in the related github issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1876

Answer (score -4):

Sounds like you want to create an icon font from an svg file. Follow the following steps:

1. Go to https://icomoon.io/app/#/select
2. Click **Import icons** on the top left
3. Navigate to the svg file you want to create an icon from. select it and click **open**
4. You should see your icon on the iconmoon web page. Click on it
5. Click **generate font** on the bottom right
6. You should see your icon on the new page. Hover on it
7. Click **get code**
8. The code should look something like this

```css
.icon-home2:before {
    content: "\e900";
}
```

8.1 Copy the code and paste it at the top of your scss or css file.

9. Click the **download** button on the bottom right.
10. In the new zip folder, go to **fonts** folder and copy paste eot, svg, ttf and woff files to a some location within your application.
11. Write the following code at the top of your SCSS file (above the code you copy pasted previously)

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'newFont';
    src:url('<location of your eot file>');
    src:url('<location of your eot file>?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('<location of your woff file>') format('woff'),
        url('<location of your ttf file>') format('truetype'),
        url('<location of your svg file>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

12. Assign the new styling to your dom node (in this case a node with class **icon-home2**)
13. You final scss(or css) should look something like this.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'newFont';
    src:url('<location of your eot file>');
    src:url('<location of your eot file>?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('<location of your woff file>') format('woff'),
        url('<location of your ttf file>') format('truetype'),
        url('<location of your svg file>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon-home2:before {
    content: "\e900";
    font-family: "newFont";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f47920;
}
```

Comment: -1 for promoting a specific tool (and does not answer the question). Regarding the suggested approach, there are a lot of reasons not to use fonts for icons (https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Wow, I was not aware of the pros and cons, will definitely consider these in future. Regarding the answer, it was based on interpretation plus personal experience rather than tool promotion. The question is clearer now and comments have been noted.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question being asked.  Icon fonts aren't the only reason to use SVGs:  they're also used as general background images and sprite sheets.